# Issues with header for float-only pages

Tags: floats, header-footer

I'm having issues with headers in float-only pages: the header becomes all uppercase, the page number is moved from the footer to the header, and the side in which the section/subsection should be displayed is changed. The headrule also disappears. After the float-only pages, headers go back to normal.

I have the following in my preamble, but doesn't seem to be working:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\rightmark}}
```

Note - I do not decide which pages are float-only pages in my document, that depends on the size of the float and whether more text fits in the page. Therefore, a single-float approach would not be ideal.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's an MWE. I've added most of the packages I use in my document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside] {report}
\usepackage{natbib, amsmath, amssymb, lmodern, upgreek, txfonts, graphicx, mwe, microtype, textcomp, authblk, hyperref, booktabs, mathtools} 
\usepackage{floatpag}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsubsectionmark\subsubsectionmark
\def\subsubsectionmark#1{\def\Subsubsectionname{#1}\Subsubsectionmark{#1}}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} 
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{2pt}}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

It seems the problem comes from `\usepackage{floatpag}`. Without it, the float-only page does have the number in the bottom corner (which solves the footer problem), but I also loose the header in that page, which I would like to keep.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (code from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem (which may be related to the class you are using, or a package, or ...)

Comment: @PeterWilson I have added an MWE and in the process of creating it figured out part of the problem (see post).

Comment: It seems the problem comes from `\usepackage{floatpag}`. Without it, the float-only page does have the number in the bottom corner (which solves the footer problem), but I also loose the header in that page, which I would like to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the empty brackets in

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\nouppercase\rightmark}}
```

I have added the same properties inside the empty brackets as follows:

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{\nouppercase\leftmark}{\nouppercase\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{\nouppercase\rightmark}{\nouppercase\rightmark}}
```

and it works perfectly now.
There is also no need for

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{\iffloatpage{0pt}{2pt}}
```